# Weird when running node.js on port 2011 my IIS site on port 80 shows IIS logo

Tags: iis, node.js

I ran node.js http server on a port (2011) and my normal domain reboltutorial.com on port 80, weirdly when doing so my website does show up IIS logo (which is index.html IIS shows up for default website after IIS install) instead of my normal wordpress php blog. After stopping node.js my blog reappears normally.

What's the reason, I have no dependency between the two.

Comment: I suggest checking the network requests in Chrome, if I understand the concern. I think a tad more explanation is oin order tho, because I don't understand where the IIS logo is showing up.

Comment: IIS logo is just index.html page IIS shows up for default website after IIS install (a bare site). So when I run nodejs my domain somehow redirects to default website instead of reboltutorial website.

Comment: Please provide enough node.js code to replicate the problem so we can assist. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try using unassigned [port numbers](http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers). Port 2011 is already assigned to [something](http://www.corrupteddatarecovery.com/Port/2011tcp-Port-Type-raid-cc-raid-cc.asp).

Comment: That should have no bearing on this.

Comment: No it shouldn't but it's still not a good idea to listen on assigned port numbers.

Comment: TCP ports above 1024 will not be encountered unless the local server is running very specific software and while IANA does assign 2011/TCP to 'raid-cc', it also assigns TCP/8081,2,3,4,6,7,8,9 to various services but developers *regularly* use the same ports for HTTP servers. Further, since IANA assigns a very large number of ports from 1024 to 49151, it would be a useless exercise to try to only use unassigned ports, since ports above 49151 are *reserved* for dynamic/private uses. Bottom line: use any port you want as long as it's above 1024 and less than 49151.

Comment: @Rob Raisch: Your bottom line could easily be your first line causing problems - you probably wouldn't want to (or couldn't) listen on ports of well known services such as database servers which are above 1024 and less than 49151 (in case of single machine environment).

Comment: I agree that you should not attempt to listen on ports used by other services because, surprise, it will fail. My point is that you shouldn't worry about using an assigned port for a service that is not running on your server and simply choose a port number as you see fit.

Comment: Keep in mind that the only reason IANA "assigns" ports at all is to facilitate service discovery. If you are not running the service to which a port has been assigned, feel free to use its port as your needs dictate. There is no downside to this practice.

Comment: This answer was more suitable as a comment. It does not answer the question in any way, shape or form.